# PHP SELECT returns empty using IN and implode

Tags: php, arrays, select, implode

I have been at this for almost two hours and I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something simple. I have tried multiple iterations without success. SO searches have given insights but nothing exactly like this to see were I'm going wrong. Your input will be appreciated.

I have an array built [$prime_ids] made up of user IDs (individual email addresses). This is the look of the finished array:

```
["james.pruit@abcnet.com", "dan.smith@abcnet.com", "nathan.jones@abcnet.com", ...
```

Now I need to find matches in this list against matches in a database table. Note: there can be multiple matches with the information contained in the table (meaning a single user ID may show up multiple times in the list). That is being done for a specific reason.

My understanding is I need to use implode to make this work. Here is my query:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM worksheet4 WHERE worksheet4.user_id IN (" . implode(",", $prime_ids) . ");";
$result = $dbc->query($sql_query);
```

I then run a loop to build a second array ($kp_positions). Here is my code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $kp_positions[] = $row;
}
```

This returns an empty array. While debugging I tried the same SELECT query using WHERE instead of IN and implode:

```
WHERE user_id = 'dan.smith@abcnet.com'";
```

... and it works perfectly (but only for this single-user). Thinking this might have something to do with single quotes (') in the implode statement I tried every possible combination that made sense without avail. Because this works perfectly with a single user ID, where my going wrong in my implode statement? Or, am I going about this the wrong way? Thank you.

Comment: You need to quote the parts, `IN ('" . implode("','", $prime_ids) . "')`

Comment: The reason you won't find anything "exactly like this" is because you haven't broken the problem down: your database doesn't know about PHP, and PHP doesn't know about SQL. Rather than running `$sql_query` directly, echo it to the screen, and paste it into your database manually using a tool like PHPMyAdmin or MySQL WorkBench. Get it working in there, and then you'll see how to make it work in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, in my opinion better, is to use `json_encode()` to quote it.

```
$prime_ids = array_map('json_encode', $prime_ids)
```

https://3v4l.org/HPL2o

Then *without quotes*, which `json_encode()` adds for you:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT ... IN (" . implode(",", $prime_ids) . ")";
```

This will escape quotes that may exist, which is good.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I'm certain the other suggestions have merit as well because it must be the double or single quotes I need to look at and LEARN. In the meantime, you've provided a working solution. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

if you print your query you will get something like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM worksheet4 WHERE worksheet4.user_id IN (james.pruit@abcnet.com,dan.smith@abcnet.com,nathan.jones@abcnet.com);
```

Note that each member within the "in" should be wrapped in quotes
so try to run this line:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM worksheet4 WHERE worksheet4.user_id IN ('" . implode("','", $prime_ids) . "');";
```

and get

```
SELECT * FROM worksheet4 WHERE worksheet4.user_id IN ('james.pruit@abcnet.com','dan.smith@abcnet.com','nathan.jones@abcnet.com');
```

Comment: I tried your exact configuration (even though I think it was one of my previous attempts) and it still returns an empty array. Could I ask when you say "if you print your query ..." how do you do that? (You can see I'm fairly new to this.)

Comment: you can use debugger or use this php code ` die ($sql_query); `, it's print the content of sql_query, and exit. @Neil_Tinkerer

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm going to give this technique a try to see what I can learn. Much appreciated.